# Generating a text based gamemap based on nodes and edges

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to create, use and print to console a text-based game map that roughly looks like this:

```
#16              B
#           /    | \  \ 
#15        R     R  R  R
#          |     | \|  |
#14        ?     M  M  M
#            \     \  \  \
#13           R     M  E  ?
#           /   \   |  |/
#12        ?     ?  E  ?
#          |     |  |  | \
#11        M     M  R  $  R
#          |   /      \|  |
#10        M  R        M  E
#          |  |        |/ |
#9         T  T        T  T
#          |  |      / |  |
#8         M  E     M  ?  M
#          |  |       \| \|
#7         E  M        M  ?
#        /    |      /   \|
#6      R     E     M     E
#         \     \ /     / |
#5         M     ?     M  ?
#          |     | \ /  / |
#4         M     M  M  M  ?
#        /     /  /  /  /
#3      $     M  ?  $  ?
#         \     \|/  /
#2         M     M  ?
#           \  /    /
#1          M  ?   M
#            \ | /
#0             S
```

The map generator should contain nodes of different types where a type is represented by a different character (like: "R","?","M","$", etc...) and it should be generated with a weighted randomness.

It should always start with a single node at the beginning (represented by "S" here at floor 0) and it should always end on a single node as well (represented by "B" at floor 16)

Nodes should be connected by edges (represented by |/ here).

The functionality of the edges is that on any given node you can only go to a node on a higher floor (increasing number 0-16 on the left) that is connected to the current node via an edge.

Also nodes can't be connected via an edge to more than 3 nodes on a higher level at the same time but there is always at least one edge to the higher floor available.

I'm imagining this information to be store in a dictionary that looks something like this (in reference to the map above)

```
gameMap = {'S':{"Connection 1":"M","Connection 2":"M","Connection 3":"M",},
"M":{"Connection 1": "M"},"M":{"Connection 1": "?"},"M":{"Connection 1":"?"}
#and so on...
```

But there already is an issue where the M's on the first floor aren't really distinguishable in the dictionary I created here.

My first approach was trying this with generating a list of lists containing all nodes but I have no idea how to connect these nodes with edges let alone print it out.
(In this example the nodes are mostly numbers)

```
def generate_scroll_map():
    generated_map = []
    y = 0
    for row in range(11):
        x = 0
        sup_map = []
        for column in range(5):
            if y == 0:
                if x < 1:
                    #sup_map.append(9)
                    sup_map.append("Start")

            elif y == 1:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(1)
                    
            elif y == 2:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(4)
                    
            elif y == 3:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(1)
                    
            elif y == 4:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(1)
                    
            elif y == 5:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(6)
                    
            elif y == 6:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(4)
                    
            elif y == 7:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(4)
                    
            elif y == 8:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(1)
                    
            elif y == 9:
                if x < rd.randint(4,4):
                    sup_map.append(4)
                    
            elif y == 10:
                if x < 1:
                    sup_map.append(3)
                    
                    #sup_map.append(7)      
            x +=1
        generated_map.append(sup_map)
        y +=1
    return generated_map
```

I have found the picture on the top of this post in the following source code: https://github.com/Ru5ty0ne/sts_map_oracle/releases/
But I unfortunately can't read Ruby very well so this doesn't really help me.

Thanks a lot in advance for your feedback and help and please let me know how to improve this question in any way!

Enjoy the rest of your weekend!

Comment: the data structure you use is inadequate. What you are trying to generate and represent is a directed acyclic graph (DAG). But before thinking any further about it, a question: how do you plan to deal with the issue of "crossed links" (where the topology of your DAG is not [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph))? Are you looking to force the generation to produce planar graphs only? Or are you going to show crossed links? (And if so, how?)

Comment: Hi Pierre D. Thanks a lot four answer. Unfortunately the decision making process of choosing between a planar and non-planar graph is beyond me.
I'm not a 100% certain what you mean with a "crossed link" as well?

Comment: imagine two nodes (`a` and `b`) on level 1 and two nodes (`c` and `d`) on level 2. Say some naive linking algorithm yields `a->c, a->d, b->c, b->d`. You can't show these links from level 1 to level 2 without crossing (however this happens to be a planar graph, but you can't draw it with `a`, `b` one one level and `c`, `d` on another.

Comment: ah. that's right! I don't think I would have an issue with that. Purely visually I'd probably display it with an X.

Comment: Oh, but that was just a simple example. Generally speaking, even with nodes having only between 1 and 3 links from one generation to the next, you can generate lots of complex crossings. For example, `a,b,c` each linked to each of `d,e,f`...

Comment: Ah. One of the rules I forgot to add was that an edge can never "reach wider" than one node. So "a" would at the max only be possible to reach "e" but never "f".